# Using sharepoint Designer 2013 for Custom list and User roles

Tags: sharepoint-designer

How do i hide a column/field in a list based on the users permission roles using sharepoint designer, mainly when the user is Creating a NewForm.aspx or Editform.aspx.

Comment: did you try this one: http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=daba3a3b-c338-41d8-bf52-cd897d000cf3&ID=3&Web=dbb90e85-b54c-49f4-8e97-6d8258116ca0